# Problem with UI width-height : "%" vs dimension.get('window')

Tags: react-native

So im trying to do a responsive UI ,when i put width or height "100%" in my component its not working in my screen correctly ,but when i put Dimensions.get('window').width * 1 works perfect but i dont understand why.I have read some other questions too in the forum but i still dont get it .Thats not static data?

My component name is books at the near the start of CSS code. Its a container of books.
Thanks in advance.

```
//React imports
import React, { useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View , Image, Pressable, ScrollView, Modal, Alert, Dimensions , Platform} from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
//Icon imports
import { FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons'; 
//APIs imports
import axios from 'axios';
import { Buffer } from "buffer";
//My imports
import Header from './Header';
//.Env imports
import {URL} from '@env';

export default function BooksRented() {


 return (
 
  //Container
  <View style = {styles.container}>
    
    <Header />
              
        {/* ScrollView for Rent Books */}
        <ScrollView>
          
        <View style = {{width:'80%',height:'10%',backgroundColor:'black',alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center',alignSelf:'center',marginTop:'3%',borderRadius:15,flexDirection:'row'}}>
          <FontAwesome name="book" size={24} color="white" />
          <Text style = {{color:'white',fontSize:22,marginLeft:'5%'}}>Rent Books</Text>
        </View>

        <View style = {styles.books}>
        {book2.map((item)=>{ 
          return (
            <View style = {styles.bookContainer} key = {item.id}>
              <Text style = {styles.itemTitle}>
              {item.title}
              </Text>

              {/* Here we are making a book image pressable and keep the book object to use it later as modal */}
              <Pressable style = {styles.itemImage} onPress={ () => { setBookShow(item); setModalBookVisible(!ModalBookVisible)}}>
              <Image 
                style = {{width:'100%',height:'100%',borderRadius:15 , marginTop:'5%'}}
                source = {{uri :'data:image/png;base64,' + Buffer.from(item.image.data,'hex').toString('base64')}}  
              />
              </Pressable>   
                                  
                      
            </View>
          )
        })}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>

      
    </View>
  );
}

//Components Style
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    backgroundColor:'white', 
    height:'100%',
    width:'100%'
  },
  //Each element - book
  books:{
    flexDirection:'row',
    flexWrap:'wrap',
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems:'center',
    backgroundColor:'red',
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 1, ** <-------Thats my Component **
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height * 1 ** <-------Thats my Component **
  },
  bookContainer:{
    alignItems:'center',
    justifyContent:'center',
    backgroundColor:'black',
    borderRadius:15,
    margin:'3%',
    padding:'3%',
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.35,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height * 0.30
  },
  itemTitle:{
    textAlign:'center',
    width:'80%',
    fontWeight:'bold',
    fontSize : 12,
    color:'white'
  },
  itemImage:{
    width:'90%',
    height:'80%',
    alignItems:'center',
    justifyContent:'center',
    borderRadius:15,
  },
//Modal for Books
bookModal:{
  alignItems:'center',
  height:Platform.OS ==='ios' ? '70%' : '80%',
  width:'80%',
  backgroundColor:'black',
  marginTop:Platform.OS ==='ios' ? '40%' : '19%',
  marginLeft:'10%',
  borderRadius:25,
  borderWidth:1,
  elevation:15
},
//Modal Texts
bookShowTitleText:{
  textAlign:'center',
  fontWeight:'bold',
  color:'white',
  fontSize: 15
},
bookShowCategoryText:{
  textAlign:'center',
  color:'white',
  fontSize : 15
},
textInsideModal:{
  textAlign:'center',
  color:'white',
  fontSize : 14
},
bookShowDescribeText:{
  textAlign:'center',
  fontWeight:'bold',
  fontSize : 15
},
scrollViewForDescribeModal:{
  backgroundColor:'white',
  flexDirection:'column',
  padding:'5%'
},
describeText:{
  fontSize : 15
},
//Modal pressables
pressableInsideModal:{
  borderWidth:6,
  borderRadius:11,
  elevation:5,
  backgroundColor:'grey',
  width:'45%',
  height:Platform.OS ==='ios' ? '7%' : '9%',
  paddingTop:'2%',
  alignItems:'center'
},


});
```

Comment: You can use Flex for responsive UI instead of Dimension.

Comment: I use it but still my code does not work.